# Printing a float in 8 characters with as much precision as possible

Tags: python, floating-point

I'm looking for an efficient way to print floats in Python with the highest precision possible in 8 characters.  Either `%f` or `%e` formatting can be used, depending on the number.  You can omit leading and trailing zeros, so `-0.123456` can be written `-.123456`.  If scientific notation is used, you can also omit the "e" so `-1.234e-8` can be written `-1.234-8`.

I'm basically looking for a faster version of this:
http://code.google.com/p/pynastran/source/browse/trunk/pyNastran/bdf/fieldWriter.py#80

After profiling, I found that my code was spending about half its time in the linked routine, which is called hundreds of thousands of times.

Comment: What are you going to use it for?

Comment: What makes you say the linked code is too slow?

Comment: @ATOzTOA - My program is writing an input file for NASTRAN, a structural analysis tool.  It allows some quirky variations in float formatting.

Comment: It looks like there's an assert in your linked function, which would be impacting performance. Have you tried taking it out?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Removing the asserts did not have an appreciable impact.

Comment: #1 I got a very small (-0.3/6.2) speed bump from replacing the `abs` call with `value <= tol and -tol <= value`
#2 I did get a small (-0.4/5.9) speed bump from taking out the `assert`
#3 halved the runtime by using pypy. If you're not already doing that, you should.

I mean, I could keep going through and trying to find the pennies and dimes like #1 and #2, but it sounds like you're looking for (int)x speed gains; I might look at the underlying format, but other than pypy don't see anything obvious.

Comment: Another thing: line 103 recomputes field. Also another assert on line 128.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit a different direction but using python3-64 have a large number of decimals using the built **decimal module**.

http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/decimal.html#

Here is an example:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 20
>>> D = decimal.Decimal
>>> D('1')/D('22')
Decimal('0.045454545454545454545')
>>> getcontext().prec = 40
>>> D('1')/D('22')
Decimal('0.04545454545454545454545454545454545454545')
>>>
```

PS. As terms & conditions always apply, please do check the notes on sequential operations: http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/decimal.html#mitigating-round-off-error-with-increased-precision

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using Python 2.7.  Also, I don't really need a ton of precision since I only have 8 characters to work with.  I just want to vary the number of decimal places with the magnitude of the number so I use all 8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best I was able to come up with.  It's a bit more readable (in my opinion) than the function I was using before, but it's no faster.

```
def print_float_8(val, tol=0.0):
    if abs(val) <= tol:
        return '      0.'
    if val < 0:
        return print_float_neg_8(val)
    else:
        return print_float_pos_8(val)

def print_float_pos_8(val):
    if val < 0.01 or val > 100000:
        return print_float_sci_pos_8(val)
    if val < 0.1:
        f = '%8.6g' % val
    else:
        f = '%8.7g' % val
    if len(f) > 8:
        f = f.lstrip('0')
    return f

def print_float_sci_pos_8(val):
    if val < 1.0e-9:
        f = ('%10.3e' % val).replace('e-', '-')
    elif val < 1:
        f = ('%10.4e' % val).replace('e-0', '-')
    elif val <= 1.0e9:
        f = ('%10.4e' % val).replace('e+0', '+')
    else:
        f = ('%10.3e' % val).replace('e+', '+')
    return f.strip()

def print_float_neg_8(val):
    if val > -0.01 or val < -10000:
        return print_float_sci_neg_8(val)
    if val > -0.1:
        f = '%8.5g' % val
    else:
        f = '%8.6g' % val
    if len(f) > 8:
        f = f.replace('-0.', '-.')
    return f

def print_float_sci_neg_8(val):
    if val > -1.0e-9:
        f = ('%-8.2e' % val).replace('e-', '-')
    elif val > -1:
        f = ('%-8.3e' % val).replace('e-0', '-')
    elif val >= -1.0e9:
        f = ('%-8.3e' % val).replace('e+0', '+')
    else:
        f = ('%-8.2e' % val).replace('e+', '+')
    return f.strip()
```